# How to order levels of a factor in R H2O

Tags: r, h2o

I'm trying to set an order for the levels of a factor in R H2O. Example `x: factor w/5 levels "3" "4" "5" "1" "2"`. `df` is the dataframe.

I tried this:
With `h2o.setLevels(df$x, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))`, I'm able to rearrange the levels TO "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", but not set the order I need with 1 as lowest and 5 as highest.
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

The function you're looking for is called [`h2o.relevel()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.relevel.html).  The `h2o.setLevels()` function only allows you to change the names of the levels, but `h2o.relevel()` will allow you to change the order of the levels.

EDIT:
Here's an example.

```
> hf <- as.h2o(iris)
> h2o.levels(hf['Species'])
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 
> hf['Species'] <- h2o.relevel(hf['Species'], y = "virginica")
> h2o.levels(hf['Species'])
[1] "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor"
```

Comment: There is a problem with h2o.relevel; I tried to get the min or max using h2o.which_min(df$x) and h2o.which_max, but the output is NAN. This tells me that h2o.relevel does not set a decreasing order for instance. How can I achieve that? Thank you

Comment: The `h2o.which_min()` and `h2o.which_max()` functions don't work on factor columns.  I have updated my answer above to show an example so you can see that it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what H2O is, but in general

```
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

would work